# Binance staking api, i cant imprt

Tags: python, binance

```
import logging

from binance.spot import Spot as Client

from binance.lib.utils import config_logging

from binance.error import ClientError

config_logging(logging, logging.DEBUG)

key = ""
secret = ""

params = {"product": "STAKING"}

client = Client(key, secret)

try:
    response = client.staking_product_list(**params)
    logging.info(response)
except ClientError as error:
    logging.error(
        "Found error. status: {}, error code: {}, error message: {}".format(
            error.status_code, error.error_code, error.error_message
        )
    )
```

Above is the code on GitHub for Binance's API on getting the staking products. When i run it this error comes up:

```
from binance.spot import Spot as Client

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.spot'
```

Can anyone help on this, i am quite new to api's.

original code: https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python/blob/master/examples/spot/staking/staking_product_list.py

Comment: have you installed binance?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that this is very similar as in this thread.

[https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/47](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/477)

As per solution:

1. Try to add the the package path into environment variables.
2. change the value "include-system-site-packages" in the file pyvenv.cfg of your project from "false" to "true"
3. Make sure you installed both 'binance' and 'python-binance' modules as discussed in

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/31299/

4. Use older version of the package

```
    pip install python-binance==<older_version_number>
```

Comment: Their mistake was naming their script binance which didn't allow them access to any of the files after installing the package binance. The problem I think i'm having is there is no binance.spot or binance.error